# (Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType

Tags: java, soap, axis

I am getting below error on executing following command line to generate Java class from WSDL.

***WSDL2Java.bat -uri http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL -o C:\Sachin***

```
Error:Using AXIS2_HOME:   C:\axis2-1.6.2
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre
Retrieving document at 'http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL'.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.
WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'propertyName'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'propertyType'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'shortTypeNameUncapped'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'shortTypeName'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'javaName'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'inputcount'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'inputcount'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'propertyName'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'propertyType'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'shortTypeNameUncapped'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'shortTypeName'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'javaName'
(Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType'
```

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error is due to IBM JDK. I faced similar problem. After I switched to Oracle JDK problem got resolved.

Please set your JAVA_HOME variable to Oracle JDK home and it will resolve the issue.

All the best.